# Using a variable name after the where clause in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a PHP string to create an SQL statement which uses a variable for a field name after the WHERE clause. The problem is that it doesn't use the variable name, I'm not good with PHP so not sure if it's my string concatenation or something else... any help would be appreciated! I'm using PHP 5.5 with mysql, as mysqli isn't available with  my current host.

```
echo $sql_subject;
$sqlString2 = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE  ". $sql_subject . " = '$set'";
```

However it keeps outputting:

```
S
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE '' = '1'
```

I know the $sql_subject has a value because it's printing above the SQL output... I'd like it to say:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE S = '1'
```

Thanks

Comment: You may *know* that `$sql_subject` *should* have a value.  But clearly, it does not.  Perhaps there is a subtle typo somewhere.

Comment: Could you share more of your code? There isn't an error in what you have posted. (And creating your query this way can open you up to SQL-injects)

Comment: You have to show us real code. There is '' in the outputted query, so somewhere in your script the value of $sql_subject changes

Comment: The output does not match the code you give. You are not outputting your SQL statement, yet it is in your output. That is a bigger miracle than the one you are raising as an issue. As @Philipp wrote: show your real code.